# How to get value of custom data attribute in ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to get the value of my custom data attribute in ionic. I tried so many ways but none of them worked for me.This is my ion-select:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-select value="اصفهان" (ionChange)="getCities($event)" [(ngModel)]="model.united" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" ok-text="تایید" cancel-text="کنسل">
    <ion-select-option value="{{item.name}}" data-id="{{item.id}}" *ngFor="let item of provinces">{{item.name}}</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

I want to get 'data-id' in my method.This is the method:

```
getCities($event) {
  const provinceId= $event.target.getAttribute('data-id');
}
```

But it returns null. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `item` directly as value instead of `item.name` and use in your function directly like

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-select value="اصفهان" (ionChange)="getCities($event)" [(ngModel)]="model.united" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" ok-text="تایید" cancel-text="کنسل">
    <ion-select-option [value]="item" *ngFor="let item of provinces">{{item.name}}</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

component function

```
getCities($event) {
  console.log($event, $event.id);
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it returns"undefiend"

Comment: undefined for `$event` or `$event.id` ?

Comment: sorry my mistake. I changed "data-id" value but you changed value. Now it's working. thank's

Answer (score 0):

`target` property doesn't have the `getAtrribute`.The `getAtrribute` property is available in `$event` object.

try below code

```
getCities($event) {
  const provinceId= $event.getAttribute('data-id');
}
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-set-access-data-attribute-binding?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I tried this but it has this error:"$event.getAttribute is not a function"

Comment: keep custom data inside square bracket like `<input type="hidden" class="test" value="0" [custom-data]="data.id" />`.